# Extjs 4.2 combo - clear listeners from the BoundList

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

How can I remove the `listConfig` listeners from my ComboBox:

```
    var combo = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
        valueField : 'id',
        store: store,
        displayField : 'description',
        editable : true,
        autoSelect : false,
        forceSelection : false,
        allowBlank : true,
        typeAhead : false,
        mode : 'local',
        listConfig : {
            listeners : {
                itemclick : function(){ console.log('listConfig listeners itemclick');  }
                }
        }
    });
```

I tried `combo.listConfig.clearListeners()`, but the `listConfig` member here seems just to be the configuration (no methods).  I need access to the actual `Ext.view.BoundList` for the Combo, so I can call `clearListeners()` on it, but there doesn't seem to be a getter for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
combo.getPicker().clearListeners()
```